# Java Array List - finding duplicate in While loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I tried solving this ArrayList problem but no luck

Anyway in while loop I have to add new String items to the ArrayList.

If there is a duplicate item there should be a message that says REPEATED ITEM.

While loop will break by word END

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList<String> lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("enter words: ");
        lista1.add(in.nextLine());
        if(lista1.containsAll(lista1)){
            System.out.println("Repeated words");
        }
        if(lista1.contains("end")) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(String data:lista1)
        System.out.println(data);
}
```

Comment: "`lista1.containsAll(lista1)`" is always true, isn't it?

Comment: You should probably check *before* inserting the new item

Comment: As the users enters word while loop checks if the current word is already in the List. Maybe I am wrong with this containsAll. Today is my first day with ArrayLists so I am still confused with them

Comment: Ok, but if you add it to the list before checking, by definition it will always be in the list when you check, won't it? You should read the word into a string, check whether it's there with `lista1.contains(theWord)` and if it returns false, add the word to the list.

Comment: Federico thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, I believe it appears that you're trying to loop over user input until they type "end", each input to a list, and state if you already added that word by printing out "repeated word". If that's the case, you're pretty close. You just need to understand how to use the list data structure a little bit better.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("enter words: ");
        String userInput = in.nextLine();
        if (lista1.contains(userInput)) { // checks if user's input is already in lista1
            System.out.println("Repeated word: " + userInput);
        } else { // if it's not, then add user's input to lista1
            lista1.add(userInput);
        }
        if (lista1.contains("end")) { // if lista1 contains "end", exit loop
            break;
        }
    }

    for(String data:lista1)
        System.out.println(data);

}
```

Comment: If you're only going to add when it's not already present, you may as well use a `Set`, e.g. a `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: Exactly, but my guess is that they are new to linked lists. If so, they should stick with it until they understand how to utilize it before moving on.

Comment: there are no linked lists involved here.

Comment: Okay my bad, "lists" in general then.

Comment: No problem, if my answer works for you, don't forget to give it an up arrow =] Happy coding!